# Intellij: Used grayed 'unused property'

Tags: intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ 2020.1
I have file with all properties used in project, and I have problem with 'unused property' annotation.
While annotation is used in string constants - it's grayed in IntelliJ.
Do You know how to mark properties used in string constants as used in IntelliJ?

[image]